# Get list of outdated plugins in the rest api?

Tags: plugins, rest-api

Using `/wp-json/wp/v2/plugins` get you a list of plugins but it doesnt show if it is outdated or not. Is there a API route that allows you to check if a plugin is outdated/is oa older version? same with themes.

Comment: I don’t think so, but you could look at the site transient values the update check process writes (update_plugins or similar) and probably use that to extend the REST endpoint. Why do you want to do this though?

Comment: Depending on your usecase, you could use an api feed from Patchstack. This will allow you to determine outdated plugins and vulnerabilities also.

Answer (score 2):

> Get list of outdated plugins in the rest api?

It looks like you would need to create your own custom REST API endpoints using `get_plugin_updates()` and `get_theme_updates()` to list available updates.

Note that these display cached data and don't trigger a request to wp.org api.